# Why mounting an ISO is faster than extracting it?

Tags: mount, iso

When I tried to extract (used right click and extract) a 2Gb ISO file it took a lot of time. I tried to mount the ISO using `-o loop` and its works fast. Why is it so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should clarify what you mean by *extracting* but as far as I understood:

- in the first case you copy each file and folder out of the ISO file. By making a copy you need to read everything and write everything to a different location
- mounting just makes the content available but does nothing else (no copy thus no read/write). The content is available as part of the file system but is read only when you make an operation on a file.

Comment: How mounting makes content available without reading?

Comment: I edited the answer: the files and folders are available but are not read until copied/opened/...

Comment: When you mount it, all it does is read the index of files/folders from the ISO which tells the operating system the name and starting block of each file. So reading that is trivial, that's why it is fast and that's what is meant by "making content available".